Procesar CSV en Java con Stream
Hola buenas tardes estoy teniendo problemas al intentar procesar un CSV, si bien pude leer el archivo tengo problemas al separar los campos del array con split, lo que hace es tomar solo una parte del campo separado por pipes y me guarda toda la linea en un array de un solo indice o a cada letra de la linea en un indice distinto.
public static void loadDetailRowList(String csvFilePath) {
    String delim = "(?<!\\\\)|";

    repositoryDetailRowList = readTxtFileLines(csvFilePath)
            .stream()
            .skip(1)
            .map(l -> Arrays.stream(l.split(delim, 9))
                    .map(el -> el
                            .replaceAll("\\\\|", "|")
                            .trim())
                    .toArray(String[]::new))

            .map(arr -> repositoryMapper.map(arr))
            .toList();
}

dejo la funcion repositoryMapper para que se entienda lo que quiero hacer
static Mapper<String[], RepositoryDetailRow> repositoryMapper = (arr) -> {
    try {
        System.out.println(arr[REPOSITORY_ID_INDEX]);
        System.out.println(arr[REPOSITORY_NAME_INDEX]);

        return new RepositoryDetailRow(
                arr[REPOSITORY_NAME_INDEX],
                arr[DESCRIPTION_INDEX],
                Double.parseDouble(arr[STARS_INDEX]),
                arr[URLS_INDEX],
                arr[USER_NAME_INDEX]
        );
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
    }
};


aca hay un ejemplo de como se proceso el csv:
|1|
|f|
claramente hay mas cosas pero solo me esta tomando el primer caracter de cada campo

Recuerda que el pipe | , se considera un caracter especial, por lo que debes escapar correctamente este caracter de la siguiente forma:
\\|

por lo tanto el REGEX que necesitas e
s:
String delim = "(?<!\\\\)\\|";  //*Correcto  
//String delim = "(?<!\\\\)|"; //*Incorrecto  

Este sería el código:
public static void loadDetailRowList(String csvFilePath) {
    String delim = "(?<!\\\\)|";

    repositoryDetailRowList = readTxtFileLines(csvFilePath)
            .stream()
            .skip(1)
            //.map(l -> Arrays.stream(l.split(delim, 9))
            .map(l -> Arrays.stream(l.split(delim))
                    .map(el -> el
                            .replaceAll("\\\\|", "|")
                            .trim())
                    .toArray(String[]::new))

            .map(arr -> repositoryMapper.map(arr))
            .toList();
}


Gracias, me sirvio pero tengo que aprender más sobre expresiones regulares porque me dio otro error en una linea que tiene pipes encerrados entre comillas dobles

Excelente, puedes agregar otra pregunta para que la comunidad te ayude nuevamente, saludos @MaximilianoBarrera
